# ModelForm and error_css_class

Tags: python, django, django-forms

my problem is simple. Where the right place for a custom error_css_class value is when using ModelForm?

I tried this:

```
class ToolForm(ModelForm):
error_css_class = 'wrong_list'
class Meta:
    model = Tool
    widgets = {
               'name' : TextInput(attrs={'class': 'small_input corners'}),
               'description' : Textarea(attrs={'cols': 20, 'rows': 5, 'class': 'text corners'}),
               'stocks' : TextInput(attrs={'class': 'small_input corners'}),
               'state' : Textarea(attrs={'cols': 25, 'rows': 6, 'class': 'text corners'}),
    }
```

Also, I tried as a class Meta value. Doesn't work either.

By now I just changed my css to 'errorlist' (u know, the default one), buuut this kind of doubts make me unhappy :P.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own error list class by inherting from django's `ErrorList`.  See the docs for details:

- [Customizing the error list format](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#customizing-the-error-list-format)

Note that you'll have to override the method to output the full HTML and can't just replace CSS class.  You could call the base method and do a string replace on "class=\"errolist\"" and return the output.

Comment: Nice, I did that way, nevertheless I just wanted to change the css value, is there a way of changing that value directly?

Thanks dude.

Comment: Unfortunately not -- it seems it's hard coded in the generated HTML: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/util.py#L36

Answer (score 0):

**create** custom class thath extends ErrorList

```
class CustomErrorList(ErrorList):
    def get_context(self):
        return {
            "errors": self,
            "error_class": "your css class",
        }
```

And add it in your form class:

class CustomForm(ModelForm):
def **init**(self, *args, **kwargs):
super().**init**(*args, **kwargs)
self.error_class = CustomErrorList